# RPi 4 - 8 nodes - Appropriate switch for POE

Tags: pi-4, cluster

I was thinking about an 8 port switch that can provide my 8 RPi's 4 power over POE.

I think i have found one according to my needs ( small dimensions), namely the: Ubiquiti EdgeSwitch 10XP - https://www.ui.com/edgemax/edgeswitch-10xp/

With a PoE budget:  150W

Would this be sufficient?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103972/discussion-on-question-by-nicojuicy-rpi-4-8-nodes-appropriate-switch-for-poe).

Answer (score 1):

The actual Pi PoE hat wants 48V, this switch can only deliver 24V. Connecting the two together won't necessarily blow up the hat, but it will not work.

It doesn't mean you won't be able to make [custom PoE adapters](https://hackaday.com/2019/09/30/using-poe-with-a-raspberry-pi-3-for-about-two-bucks/) which work with 24V. 150W is plenty of power for 8 Pi 4, even considering power losses.

Answer (score -1):

Answering for posterity since the power budget is a moot point:

No, this switch will not work as it is NOT standards compliant 802.3af (or the newer 802.3at) PoE. It not working is actually best case, the non-compliant power may actualy destroy whatever you plug on the other end.

Digressing briefly to shame Ubiquity who is otherwise great, this switch exisits because they sell (or sold? They may have changed their ways in recent times) lower cost devices that are cheaper to make since they lack "active" (aka standards compliant) PoE circuitry.